# Problems updating packages in Linux Mint

Tags: upgrade, linux-mint, dpkg

I'm having some issues when updating packages in **Linux Mint 21.1 Vera**. When I start the update manager and try to install all the updates, this pop-up appears

[Error pop-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl8cO.jpg)

Then, if I take this advice and run dpkg command (***dpkg --configure -a***) as follows

[dpkg command run in prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rr0z.jpg)

dpkg automatically removes my older rtl driver (rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1). After removal, rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 is built again for my current kernel version (5.15.0-58-generic) and updates can be done without problems, but this doesn't finishes here.

The problem comes after reboot, when I find my network manager does not find connections at all. It remembers me older problems with older mint versions in which I had network adapter problems.

[No connections available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w8Lr.jpg)

Any suggestions? my notebook is an HP Pavilion 15-eh0009la.

Sorry for the lack of inline pictures (I still do not have enough points for it) and the non-so-pretty edition (just screenshots). I could not install a proper image editor due to the same problem.

Luckily, timeshift came to save us from things like these. I may follow some indications made in

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307

since my notebook is still of the same brand as when I made this before, also with Linux Mint. Now, I may look for other drivers.. I don't know.